# Why did the Georgia Railroad and Banking Company have a banking company?

Tags: united-states, banking, railroads

I am reading newspapers from Savannah, GA 1842 (Oct. & Nov.) and they often mention the [Georgia Railroad and Banking Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_Railroad_and_Banking_Company) (originally called Georgia Railroad Company). I am not understanding quite completely the issues with the Georgia Central Bank and if they apply to why or why not the Railroad company had its own banking company. Can I get an explanation if the two are related or not and most importantly why did the Georgia Railroad and Banking Company have its own bank part?

Comment: There might be a similar history with Wells Fargo & Company (now Wells Fargo bank). I believe the same founders also founded American Express. I suspect that banking and transportation were closely connected back then.